# The bot command works, but crashes after multiple uses. I get the error "Unknown interaction"

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I just finished coding my discord bot, and all commands work without a hitch except one. The timeout.js works, but after multiple uses the entire bot crashes and I have to restart. Unsure on the why. I'm hoping it's either missing an "await" in the statement or missing a ";". Does anyone have any idea?

````
const ms = require("ms")

module.exports = {
    name: "timeout",
    description: "This command puts a user in the server in timeout!",
    permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
    options: [
        {
            name: "put",
            description: "Puts the user in timeout!",
            type: "SUB_COMMAND",
            options: [
                {
                    name: "member",
                    description: "Specify the member you want to put in timeout!",
                    type: "USER",
                    required: true
                },
                {
                    name: "duration",
                    description: "Specify the duration of the timeout!",
                    type: "STRING",
                    required: true
                },
                {
                    name: "reason",
                    description: "Specify the reason for this timeout!",
                    type: "STRING",
                    required: false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "remove",
            description: "This option removes the user from timeout!",
            type: "SUB_COMMAND",
            options: [
                {
                   name: "member",
                   description: "Specify the member you want to remove from timeout!",
                   type: "USER",
                   required: true 
                },
                {
                    name: "reason",
                    description: "Specify the reason you want to remove the timeout!",
                    type: "STRING",
                    required: false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    /**
     * 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
    async execute(interaction){

        const choice = interaction.options.getSubcommand()
        const user = interaction.options.getUser('member')
        const duration = interaction.options.getString('duration')
        const reason = interaction.options.getString('reason') ?? `No reason provided.`
        const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)

        if (user === interaction.member.user) return interaction.reply({
            embeds: [new MessageEmbed({
                color: '#5104DB',
                description: 'You can\'t use this command on yourself.'
            })], ephemeral: false
        })

        if (user === interaction.client.user) return interaction.reply({
            embeds: [new MessageEmbed({
                color: '#5104DB',
                description: 'You can\'t use this command on me.'
            })], ephemeral: false
        })

        if (user.bot === true) return interaction.reply({
            embeds: [new MessageEmbed({
                color: '#5104DB',
                description: 'You can\'t use this command on bots.'
            })], ephemeral: false
        })

        switch (choice) {
            case 'put':
                try {
                    const durationMs = ms(duration)
                    if (!durationMs) return interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [new MessageEmbed({
                            color: '#5104DB',
                            description: 'Please specify a valid duration for timeout.'
                        })], ephemeral: false
                    })
                    await interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [new MessageEmbed({
                            color: '#5104DB',
                            description: 'Putting user in timeout...'
                        })], ephemeral: false
                    })
                   await member.timeout(durationMs, reason)
                    interaction.editReply({
                        embeds: [new MessageEmbed({
                            color: '#5104DB',
                            description: `${user} is successfully put in timeout.\n\n**Duration:** ${duration}\n**Reason:** ${reason}`
                        })]
                    })
                } catch (e) {
                    await interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [new MessageEmbed({
                            color: '#5104DB',
                            description: `An error occurred:\n\n${e}`
                        })], ephemeral: false
                    })
                }
                break;
            case 'remove':
                try {
                    await interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [new MessageEmbed({
                            color: '#5104DB',
                            description: 'Removing user from timeout...'
                        })], ephemeral: false
                    })
                   await member.timeout(null, reason)
                    interaction.editReply({
                        embeds: [new MessageEmbed({
                            color: '#5104DB',
                            description: `${user} is successfully removed from timeout.\n\n**Reason:** ${reason}`
                        })]
                    })
                } catch (e) {
                    await interaction.reply({
                        embeds: [new MessageEmbed({
                            color: '#5104DB',
                            description: `An error occurred:\n\n${e}`
                        })], ephemeral: false
                    })
                }
                break;
        };
    },
};```
````

Comment: Does it show an error in the terminal/console when the bot crashes? If so, please send the error

Comment: the command works, but after the second or third input of the command, i get "Unknown interaction" in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

There might be different reasons:

- Interaction might be timed out after 3 sec
- Interaction has already been replied

Instead of using `interaction.reply` I would recommend initially using `interaction.deferReply` and then `interaction.editReply` when message is ready for example

```
await interaction.deferReply();

const result = await longWaitingMethod(email);

await interaction.editReply({ 
   content: result.error || result.success, 
   ephemeral: true 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use interaction try this:

`await interaction.response.defer()`
`await interaction.edit_original_response("message")`

This helps you give time to get to the answer to be posted.